# Conjugating Vされる, Vさせる form: just treat as ichidan?

Tags: grammar, verbs, conjugations

Is it gramatically correct to treat causative, passive, and causative-passive forms of verbs as ichidan る ending verbs when negating them or creating their past tense?

Comment: Actually you are already treating causative forms as *ichidan* verbs when turning them into causative-passive forms by adding られる to their stems, which always end with the vowel /e/. The causative-passive form is nothing but the passive form of a causative form.